# MDL grid layout not responsive

Tags: layout, responsive-design, material-design-lite

I'm having issues getting my code: (http://codepen.io/hoschiCZ/pen/rOJmmr) to work.

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The title doesn't matter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title"><center>MDL test</center></span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="mdl-grid" style="margin: 0px">
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--hide-phone mdl-cell--1-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-desktop">
        <!-- An empty block of space, maybe some ads here? -->
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-phone mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--6-col-desktop">
        There is the main text/content located. This has to stay visible at all costs and screen sizes.
        <br><small>Material Design Lite courtesy of Google, Inc.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--hide-phone mdl-cell--1-col-tablet mdl-cell--3-col-desktop">
        <!-- An empty block of space, maybe some ads here? -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The intended columns layout & counts are as follows:

```
Desktop 3-6-3
Tablet 1-6-1
Phone 0-4-0
```

The outer numbers/cols are probably space for ads or just empty space, is just looks bad otherwise.

The problem is: it's not responsive, even after refreshing pages. I tried Chromium Linux mobile/tablet emulation and Nexus 5 Firefox & Chrome. Everywhere, the desktop version is used.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code in the question instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDL requires you to include this in the header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Btw I didn't see it written in the Getting Started guide, maybe add it there?

Working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGEyVz)

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

into

`<head></head>`

Comment: Please provide a working example, for instance a jsfiddle.

Comment: duplicate with what I submitted, although with broken formatting. Adding JSFiddle now.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you haven't wrapped your **.mdl-grid** in a **.mdl-layout__content**

```
<div class="mdl-layout__content">
<div class="mdl-grid">row</div>
</div>
```

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruh96Lvx/3/) example for you.
Just expand the window slider and you'll see what you are desiring.